# Xtext terminal rule for float

Tags: dsl, xtext

I have tried to define a float type in Xtext however I receive a error message when generate aritifact :

```
    The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input:RULE_FLOAT,RULE_INT
```

My terminal for float is as follows:

```
    terminal FLOAT returns ecore::EFloat: INT '.' INT;
```

My float is to replicate a float that is able to be accepted by Java:
1.1 , 
1 ,
0.1

Answer (score 0):

Terminal rules are order dependent. The first match usually wins. Your grammar seems to contain another rule that already matches INT.INT but that's impossible to tell from the information that you provide. Generally speaking it's a good idea to use [data type](http://zarnekow.blogspot.de/2012/11/xtext-corner-6-data-types-terminals-why.html) rules to describe the syntax of floats.

That would read (note the missing terminal keyword):

```
Float returns ecore::EFloat: INT '.' INT;
```

Comment: thank you very much. your blog is one of useful xtext resource archive !